# Counting Number of Swaps in QuickSort in Python

Tags: python, quicksort

I'm trying to count the number of swaps made in Quick Sort without using a global variable. I tried something similar this [Quick Sort Comparison Counter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840639/quick-sort-comparison-counter-in-python) post, but am not getting the correct number of swaps made. My code is below, and the test case is returning 1, but it should return 3. Any insight on how to change it to get the correct swap counts?

Edit: the issue was with my algorithm, not the swap counter. I've updated the code to return i instead of j, and increment j up to the end. The number of swaps went up significantly, but I think it's accurate?

```
def _partition(input_list, begin, end):
    # For counting the number of swaps
    count = 0
    # Picks the last number in the list as the pivot
    pivot = input_list[end]

    i = begin
    j = begin
    while j < end:
        if input_list[j] < pivot:
            count += 1
            input_list[i], input_list[j] = input_list[j], input_list[i]
            i += 1
        j += 1

    count += 1
    input_list[i], input_list[end] = input_list[end], input_list[i]
    return i, count


def _quickSort(input_list, begin, end):
    count = 0
    if begin < end:
        pivot, count = _partition(input_list, begin, end)
        count += _quickSort(input_list, begin, pivot-1)
        count += _quickSort(input_list, pivot + 1, end)
    return count


def quickSort(input_list, begin=None, end=None):
    if begin == None:
        begin = 0
    if end == None:
        end = len(input_list) - 1
    return _quickSort(input_list, begin, end)


test = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7]
counter = quickSort(test)
print(counter)
print(test)

test2 = [3, 7, 6, 9, 1, 8, 10, 4, 2, 5]
counter1 = quickSort(test2)
print(counter1)
print(test2)
```

Comment: Did you try checking that the results from each recursive call are what you expect?

Comment: As an aside, you don't need or want a function to swap elements in a Python implementation. The Pythonic swap is simply `l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]`. And don't use `list` as a name; that hides the built-in name for the type itself.

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel I made the Pythonic updates, and as it turns out, the issue was with my algorithm, not the swap counter.

Comment: @Ivy Comment for the case if you not overriding `partition` function: do you know that `partition` function is already exist in the Python and if you want to use `partition` default py function in this project it may cause problems?